# How to fill a Path in Android with a linear gradient?

Tags: android, graphics, path, fill

Given a closed Path object result is like this:

[image]

Although that is a rectangle I'm looking for something which works with any closed Path.

Comment: A brilliant, no, a fantastic question!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

While steelbytes' answer will probably give you more control over the individual sections of the gradient, you can do it without the path:

```
Paint m_Paint = new Paint();
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // start at 0,0 and go to 0,max to use a vertical
    // gradient the full height of the screen.
    m_Paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPaint(m_Paint);
}
```

Comment: ok but NEVER construct the Paint instance in the onDraw(...) methods

Comment: @ebtokyo: For performance reasons? Would you cache it on creation and and update its size on each onDraw (or maybe in resize)?

Comment: Yes, for performance reasons. Lint comments allocations in onDraw() like this:

"Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)"

Comment: @ebtokyo: also LinearGradient instance should be pr-instansiated in another stage on the view lifycle

Comment: @TalKanel You cannot modify `LinearGradient`, so you have to reinstantiate it. Maybe not in `onDraw`, but in `onLayout` or in `onMeasure`. But you will get a lint warning anyhow.

Answer (score 32):

this may help.

Note: it's not efficient to create the Paint etc in every call to onDraw. This is just an demonstration of LinearGradient shader

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG|Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    Path pth = new Path();
    pth.moveTo(w*0.27f,0);
    pth.lineTo(w*0.73f,0);
    pth.lineTo(w*0.92f,h);
    pth.lineTo(w*0.08f,h);
    pth.lineTo(w*0.27f,0);
    p.setColor(0xff800000);
    p.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,h,0xff000000,0xffffffff,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    canvas.drawPath(pth,p);
}
```

Comment: bad idea to create objects (Paint, Path, ...) in method onDraw(Canvas canvas)

Comment: @igo very true. I kept the code simple to demonstrate how to use the shader.