#  How to fill a path with gradient

Tags: android

I have a graph view that draws a path to some points like this:
[image]

now I want to fill the inner area of graph with a gradient color
how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

**Edit:**
@Lumis
I added another closed path and set the shader and it was like this:
[image]

but there is a gradient color in the outer area of the graph, how can I avoid this ?

Comment: I don't know how did you close your fill path, just experiment with its shape. It may be that the point at 11, 0 is confusing the fill.

Comment: What point do you suggest to close the path correctly ?

Comment: I have no idea, just experiment and figure out how it behaves...

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: [How to fill a Path in Android with a linear gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836098/how-to-fill-a-path-in-android-with-a-linear-gradient)

You may need to draw two paths one closed for gradient and another one on top with different color for the chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble filling a path with the color, this might be some help.

https://github.com/blessenm/LineChartDemo

But here the path is filled with a color. Combining this with the link lumis gave might help you on how to fill it with a gradient.