# Android : How to draw layout with slanting and curved edges like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am unable to figure out how to design layout in android like the images shown below.
Please suggest some solutions in order to achieve the same.
[image: Rounded and spongy or flabby on animating it]

[image: Slanting edge]

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path, android.graphics.Paint) or just simply use image

Comment: This is simple geometry looking at paint and refreshing your geometry would be a good start' or use images as recommended by @LeoLink

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create custom curved in a layout, like this image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303873/create-custom-curved-in-a-layout-like-this-image)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two ways:

1- Use images in the background and position them accordingly.

2- Write your own **View** class and override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. You can get help from Android documentation.

[Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

[Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

**OR**

Check this solution for help:

[Android custom shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778177/android-custom-shape)

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said, you can create custom views in android.
The curves are called [Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)s. [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47303873/8583692) have been asked before.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073682/8583692) and [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7) might help you on how to implement the curved view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG wave for background, and you can use this [link](https://getwaves.io/) to make online.