# Define and load parameters for LinearGradient from XML

Tags: android

Instead of programatically passing parameters to create a LinearGradient.

```
new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, mWheelHeight, Color.parseColor("#4A90E2"), Color.parseColor("#50E3C2"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
```

is it possible to load the colors from XML?

Comment: Well you can set this by use of android:background="@drawable/gradient.xml"

Comment: I want to set this as the shader for the Paint instance for drawing shapes.

Comment: Not with xml but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600805/how-to-set-gradient-style-to-paint-object  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836098/how-to-fill-a-path-in-android-with-a-linear-gradient

Comment: I don't think your xml means a `LinearGradient`, it's a `Shape`.

Comment: `"I have defined a gradient in xml."` no, you have created a `Drawable`, not a "gradient" so you cannot convert it to a `Shader`

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this directly inside Paint

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```