# How to fill a Path with linear gradient in an Android custom view

Tags: android, graphics, kotlin, android-custom-view, linear-gradients

I have created an Android Custom View using Kotlin to draw a Star which will be used to create a custom RatingBar in future; So I extended the View class and override its `draw()` method to draw one Star considering this guide from Google:
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing

After that, I tried to fill the star path with linear gradient to achieve the star filling effect following this Post:
[How to fill a Path in Android with a linear gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836098/how-to-fill-a-path-in-android-with-a-linear-gradient)

```
class CustomStar constructor(context: Context, attr: AttributeSet) : View(context, attr) {

    private var paint: Paint = Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG)
    private var path: Path = Path()

    init {
        paint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, height.toFloat(), Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.draw(canvas)

        // draw the star.
        val min = Math.min(width, height).toFloat()
        // top left
        path.moveTo(0f, min * 0.3819901313f)
        // top right
        path.lineTo(min, min * 0.3819901313f)
        // bottom left
        path.lineTo(min * 0.1910982479f, min)
        // top tip
        path.lineTo(min * 0.5f, 0f)
        // bottom right
        path.lineTo(min*0.8089799735f, min)
        // top left
        path.lineTo(0f, min * 0.3819901313f)

        path.close()
        canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)
    }
}
```

As you can see in `init`, The paint object's `shader` attribute is set to  `LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, height.toFloat(), Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)` so I should expect the shape to be filled with the gradient.

But the problem is that I only get a solid filled star instead of the gradient, as showcased in the photo:

[image: Solid Filled Star]

Now the question is, why am I getting a solid color instead of gradient in the star?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill a Path in Android with a linear gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836098/how-to-fill-a-path-in-android-with-a-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The view's height is unknown at this point:

```
init {
    paint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, height.toFloat(), Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
}
```

Instead override onSizeChanged and create the LinearGradient there:

```
override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldW: Int, oldH: Int) {
    paint.shader = LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, h.toFloat(), Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR)
}
```